# ACRA is not sending via HTTPSender

Tags: java, php, android, acra

I changed to the latest ACRA Version 5.0.1.
If I am using my own send method everything runs fine.
This is a snipped from my application.java:

```
@AcraCore(reportSenderFactoryClasses= AcraSenderfactory.class,reportFormat = StringFormat.KEY_VALUE_LIST)`enter code here`
public class FSApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA
        ACRA.init(this);
    }
}
```

But if I try the build in HTTPSender i get no response, but this sender should send to the same simple php receiver
I just wanted to make things easier and use the build in httpSender.
But the simple way is not working.

```
@AcraCore(reportFormat = StringFormat.KEY_VALUE_LIST)
@AcraHttpSender(uri = "http://my.server.de/acra/acra.php",
        httpMethod = HttpSender.Method.POST)
```

The acra.php is very simple, but works fine for testing purpose. It writes only a file to the server with all values.

```
<?php
    // Outputs all POST parameters to a text file. The file name is the date_time of the report reception
    $fileName = date('Y-m-d_H-i-s').'.txt';
    $file = fopen($fileName,'w') or die('Could not create report file: ' . $fileName);
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $reportLine = $key." = ".$value."\n";
        fwrite($file, $reportLine) or die ('Could not write to report file ' . $reportLine);
    }
    fclose($file);
?>
```

Yes I included the acra-http into my build.cradle

```
compile 'ch.acra:acra-core:5.0.1'
```

compile 'ch.acra:acra-http:5.0.1'

So does anybody know where my error can be.

Comment: Turn up the logging to see what ACRA is / is not doing.

Comment: Thank you William.
Good hint.
Acra is crashing.
I will  contact ACRA-developer.
Here is the log:
                        Caused by: org.acra.sender.ReportSenderException: Error while sending KEY_VALUE_LIST report via Http POST
                                                                  at org.acra.sender.HttpSender.send(HttpSender.java:172)
                                                                  at org.acra.sender.ReportDistributor.sendCrashReport(ReportDistributor.java:109)

Comment: I just saw at the ACRA Website, that someone reported the crash 4 hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

This [issue](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/issues/626) was fixed in ACRA version 5.0.2